# Showing dialog from inside another dialog

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-dialog

How do you show a dialog from an already open dialog? Basically, nesting dialogs in Flutter.

When I try to use `showDialog();` in Flutter from inside an already created dialog(for example, by clicking some link inside a dialog, another dialog should open on top of that dialog) I get the following lint error:

[image: Flutter showDialog Lint Error]

Does any one have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting dialogs is VERY possible. You are facing an entirely different issue.

Right now, you have conflicting imports from the `custom_alert_dialog` package, and the `material.dart`.

To resolve the issue, you have to name one of the imports using the `as` keyword.

E.x

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
```

Then to use it:

```
// BEFORE 
final valueOfPi = pi;

// AFTER
final valueOfPi = math.pi
```

The syntax of everything remains the same, but whenever you want to use an object or type from the library, just add the keyword as a prefix.

Comment: Didn't work mate when I wrote `import 'blabla_custom_alert_dialog' as custom_alert_dialog` then CustomAlertDialog doesn't get detected as imported anymore

Comment: Yes, now whenever you want to use it, you have to add that prefix before. I've added an example